# Load data with scroll down in Servlet-JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, load, scroll

i'm developing a website, that has around 6000 records, and my company uses Internet Explorer 8, as its default browser (ye i know...), and it takes around 50 seconds to load the entire data. So i was trying to implement a load data function everytime the user reachs the end of the div.

Basicly the website structure its kinda like this. **Servlet - Jsp.** 
basicly when a certain jsp is requested the assigned servlet makes a doGet, and everytime a user inserts/edits/deletes a record it does a doPost, But EVERY operating is always handled by the JSP.

So any way to implement a load data when scrolling down in this case? (i want if possible not use refresh in page).

**ps: I already now that i have to use JQuery for this but not how to implement it. =).**

Comment: you're trying to implement something called 'infinite scroll'. Here's a plugin you might find useful http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well, In this case you will need to design the page with lot of javascript. What I got from the question is there is some table which is having 6000 records. Now you want to show this data on the page. You also want whenever something gets changed you want to map the changes in the screen as well.

For this, 1st thing you need is to map each row with its key on front side.
You need to read a bit of AJAX and rest is very simple.

You can hit server after a fixed interval say 5 sec. So this hit will return you the changed items. Now the max id you had on the page will be compared with the records which the server return.

Response can be of three parts:
a) deleted
b) edited
c) inserted

you can go with combining editing and inserting as at a given point you cannot track whether you might not want to have a overhead of keeping track of the same.

So only two blocks a) deleted and b) inserted/modified

while creating the view, each row will be a div with id containing the primary key. So the id of the div will be say "div23" where 23 is primary key.

Now you need to iterate the response. You can go with either XML or JSON to work this solution easily.

Lets take a sample response.

response having json bojects with ids 23, 45, 97 etc in delete and 46, 1000, 6001 etc in insert/edit.

now to delete, you need to just write: document.getElementById("div" + id).innerHTML = ""; or you can delete the same from dom model.

Similarly you can get the div and edit the same. If you do not get any div will mean that you need to insert which you can do in the end.

For ajax you can get many frameworks like prototype, dojo etc. Basic example of AJAX you can find on w3schools site.

I hope it helps.

Comment: i kinda got confused to be honest. i appreciate all the help for real. 
but now im not interested in the new, delete, edit functions. 
My only councern and doubt is, how to display... lets say... 20 records when the page loads and then every time the user scrolls down, load 20 more. im working with a table inside a div.

My goal was, how to load those 20 records everytime someone scrolls down, without refreshing the page. Or any other simple alternative.
But i've already searched alot for an example like this with jquery+servler+jsp and so far nothing...

Best regards,
and thnks

Comment: See, you contain data in a div (this will be a parent div). Now in div, you need to keep adding new elements. you have two options for this. a) you can edit its innerHTML or you can add elements through javascript. you can see creating dom object using javascript. Just an example of creating div : http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/Dynamically_Creating_a_Div_in_Javascript. you can add this div to parent div. One thing need to be taken care of is you must also remove bunch of unused divs and replace them with a String which should reduce load on browser (I beleive).

Comment: so when ever a user scroll down fetch next 20 records. It will be better to load next 40 records so that the user dont feel any delay.

Comment: and how will i do the JSP-SERVLET-JSP operations :S? thats my problem i dont know how to implement it. how to request them and trying not to refresh in that process

Comment: See, the servlet/jsp you will be calling will need to have a code such that you send a parameter in request stating the current record number. Now the jsp/servlet will return 40 records after that. you can have each record as a div with each item in it as a div or you can have a table there. To call and fetch the records from there read a bit about ajax from w3schools. It is very easy to implement. You can go with any of the framework available as well like prototype jquery etc whichever you feel you are comfirtable to work on.